# Get data from the website

Tags: php, html, curl

I have my own external website and I want to get some data from the website. I used CURL to get the content of the website however I want some part that is :

Edited : Very frankly speaking, I want to get the TimeStamp of the facebook page, If you use Inspect element on the page, you will see the code like this :

```
<span class="fsm fwn fcg"><a class="_5pcq">
<abbr title="Tuesday, June 30, 2015 at 5:00pm" data-utime="1435663826" data-shorten="1" class="_5ptz timestamp livetimestamp">5 hrs</abbr></a>
<span class="fsm fwn fcg"><a class="_5pcq">
<abbr title="Tuesday, June 30, 2015 at 5:01pm" data-utime="1435663827" data-shorten="1" class="_5ptz timestamp livetimestamp">5 hrs</abbr></a>
<span class="fsm fwn fcg"><a class="_5pcq">
<abbr title="Tuesday, June 30, 2015 at 5:02pm" data-utime="1435663828" data-shorten="1" class="_5ptz timestamp livetimestamp">5 hrs</abbr></a>
<span class="fsm fwn fcg"><a class="_5pcq">
<abbr title="Tuesday, June 30, 2015 at 5:03pm" data-utime="1435663829" data-shorten="1" class="_5ptz timestamp livetimestamp">5 hrs</abbr></a>
<span class="fsm fwn fcg"><a class="_5pcq">
<abbr title="Tuesday, June 30, 2015 at 5:04pm" data-utime="1435663830" data-shorten="1" class="_5ptz timestamp livetimestamp">5 hrs</abbr></a>
</span>
```

I just want to display the value of "data-utime" that is 1435663826. Here is my code which will fetch the contents. What should I use after this ?

```
 $cookie = tmpfile();
    $userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.64 Safari/537.31' ;

    $ch = curl_init("https://www.mywebsite.com");

    $options = array(
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 20 , 
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT => $userAgent,
        CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER => true,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => $cookie,
        CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => $cookie ,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0 ,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0
    );

    curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
    $kl = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    echo $kl; // Final output after fetching
```

Comment: Hi Jeff, can you give the complete php. i can help you to scrapping it.

Comment: That is the complete PHP !!

Answer (score 1):

You could use PHP's [DOM](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) extension to [load and parse](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) the html document and then use an instance of [DOMXPath](http://docs.php.net/domxpath) to [query](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) the specific element.

Comment: I tried a lot man. But It didn't work for me. Just because I'm fetching using CURL ?

Answer (score 0):

If you already get the html tag you can

**Try this:**

```
<?php 

$curl = curl_init('https://www.facebook.com/Rajnikant.Vs.CIDJokez'); 


curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);   
$result = curl_exec($curl); 
//echo $result; 

/* $result = 
'<span class="fsm fwn fcg"><a class="_5pcq">
<abbr title="Tuesday, June 30, 2015 at 5:00pm" data-utime="1435663826" data-shorten="1" class="_5ptz timestamp livetimestamp">5 hrs</abbr></a>
<span class="fsm fwn fcg"><a class="_5pcq">
<abbr title="Tuesday, June 30, 2015 at 5:01pm" data-utime="1435663827" data-shorten="1" class="_5ptz timestamp livetimestamp">5 hrs</abbr></a>
<span class="fsm fwn fcg"><a class="_5pcq">
<abbr title="Tuesday, June 30, 2015 at 5:02pm" data-utime="1435663828" data-shorten="1" class="_5ptz timestamp livetimestamp">5 hrs</abbr></a>
<span class="fsm fwn fcg"><a class="_5pcq">
<abbr title="Tuesday, June 30, 2015 at 5:03pm" data-utime="1435663829" data-shorten="1" class="_5ptz timestamp livetimestamp">5 hrs</abbr></a>
<span class="fsm fwn fcg"><a class="_5pcq">
<abbr title="Tuesday, June 30, 2015 at 5:04pm" data-utime="1435663830" data-shorten="1" class="_5ptz timestamp livetimestamp">5 hrs</abbr></a>
</span>';
*/
$html = $result;
$dom = new DOMDocument();

@$dom->loadHTML($html);
$a = $dom->getElementsByTagName('abbr');

$data = array();

for ($i=0; $i < $a->length; $i++) {
    $data[] = $a->item($i)->getAttribute('data-utime');

}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($data);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Well, Very fankly speaking, I want to scrap a facebook page. And want to get the first page's timestamp. The code you showed is not working. Page is : https://www.facebook.com/Rajnikant.Vs.CIDJokez
 If you use Inspect Element then you can see the timestamp of the post

Comment: Still not working!! Is that working for you ? If you use your code then it will show you the error "Update your browser"